# Why type(int_int) will be int in python?

Tags: python, variables

I find a weird thing in Python, if I assign a variable as `int_int`, `float_int`, `int_float`, the type will be `int`, `float`, `float`, seems the underline is a join character, like:

```
x = 100_200
```

then x will be a `int`, value is `100200`. Can someone explain why and how to reasonable use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.6 introduced [Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/).

Essentially, this is a readability feature.

Compare:

```
x = 100000000
```

and:

```
x = 100_000_000
```

Comment: The DV might also have been before you edited the example in, so it was a link-only answer. Or maybe they thought you should have tried harder to find a dup before answering.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered the edit.

Comment: @Chris apologies, as barmar figured, I DV'd when it was link only, ive editted to retract. May have been a bit quick to dv

Comment: @NickA, no need to apologize. Thanks for the answer edit too. It improves the readability of my answer about improving readability :-).